# Chartjs - first x-axis tick is not displayed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

As you can see in the picture the first tick (14 september) is not showed on the x axis.

[image]

Are there any options to enforce chartjs to display the tick?

Configuration for the x axis:

```
xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        time: {
            tooltipFormat: "DD-MMMM-YYYY",
            parser: function (value) {
                return moment(value).locale("RO");
            },
            displayFormats: {
                'day': 'DD MMM'
            },
            unit:'day'
        },

        display: true
    }],
```

Thank you,
Catalin

Answer (score 3):

In the x axis settings you need add :

```
scales: {
xAxes: [{
bounds: 'ticks',
}]}
```

Not sure what this changes but it will fix your problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
time: {
    round: 'day'
}
```

solved it for me

Answer (score 1):

**Chart.js v.4**
Utilizing Version 4 of Chart.js, I accomplised this by setting the bounds of the x-axis.
According to the Configuration Options documentation [chartjs.org](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/next/axes/cartesian/time.html#time-axis-specific-options), the default value is 'data'.

> The bounds property controls the scale boundary strategy (bypassed by
> min/max options).
>
> - 'data': makes sure data are fully visible, labels outside are removed
> - 'ticks': makes sure ticks are fully visible, data outside are truncated

```
scales: {
           x: {
                 bounds: 'ticks',   //here is the answer
                 type: 'time',
                 time: {
                      unit: 'day',   
                      parser: 'DD-MMMM-YYYY',
                      tooltipFormat: 'DD-MMMM-YYYY'
                  },
                  grid: {
                    display: false
                  },
                  ticks: {                            
                    color: 'black',
                    align: 'center'                            
                  }
              }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside callback you can write a logic to control the number of ticks.

```
callback(value, index, values){
    if(index === 0)
    {
        return `${value}`
    }
}
```

Hope this might help.
[For more information please refer](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#label-callback)